# Wrapping parent div immediately around floated children

Tags: jquery, css

I was wondering if it was possible to make my wrapper div scale around its floated child divs (.box) tightly when the browser is resized. At the moment, if the browser is resized the 4th div will go on to the next line however the wrapper div will stay the same size as though it is still there but I want it to scale down so it fits perfectly around the 3 divs left if that makes sense...How would I achieve this?

jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/JCGj6/

```
<div class="showcase_wrapper">
   <div class="showcase" id="pt1">
      <div class="inner">
         <div class="box"> One </div>
         <div class="box"> Two </div>
         <div class="box"> Three </div>
         <div class="box"> Four </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

.inner {
    position:relative;
}

.showcase_wrapper {
    margin:170px auto 0px auto;
    max-width:848px;
    position:relative;
}

.showcase {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    min-width:424px;
    display:inline-block;
    white-space:normal;
    float:left;
    z-index:0;
    border:1px solid #ff0000;
    background:#ff000;
}

.showcase .box {
    position:relative;
    background:#ff0000;
    width:212px;
    height:173px;
    float:left;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear your floats. And decide on a method of layout, use either positioning *or* float, not both. One will cancel out the other.

Here I have used float left on your .box divs:

```
.inner {
    }

    .showcase_wrapper {
        margin:170px auto 0px auto;
        max-width:848px;
    }

    .showcase {
        top:0;
        width:100%;
        min-width:424px;
        display:inline-block;
        white-space:normal;
        float:left;
        z-index:0;
        border:1px solid #ff0000;
        background:#ff000;
    }

    .showcase .box {
        background:#ff0000;
        width:212px;
        height:173px;
        float:left;
        cursor:pointer;
}
span.clear
{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/NnZuR/

I have removed the positioning as it's not needed when using float.

I added a span.clear to your markup to clear the floats and make the outer box respect the inner elements' dimensions. There are a few ways to clear floats, I prefer this method as having a span.clear is both semantic and makes for easy reading :)

---

The box stretching to the outer bounds of the box is default behaviour and it's best done with some javascript calculations.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    var actualWidth = $("#wrapper div").width();
    var calc = Math.max(actualWidth,Math.floor(windowWidth/actualWidth) * actualWidth);

    $("#wrapper").css({width: calc+"px"});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/cq658/

Comment: The above doesn't seem to work for FireFox (Mac OSX). The red bordered box still stretches to the furthest reaches it can as each square falls down on to the next line, rather than snapping to it's content children as the OP asks.

Comment: Even if I remove the min-width it makes no difference :-/

Comment: IT looks like this is default behaviour. http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/LRxr4/ the OP might need to use JS to calculate the width at any given moment and force it.

Comment: Yep, this was my thinking... you can either have an element that fully expands or fully contracts... there isn't such a thing as a soft-collapse *(as of yet)* without the use of JavaScript. This may be possible with flexbox once they finally decide on the implementation *(if that does ever happen)*.

Comment: Yeah, I've been playing around with the flexbox and it looks promising. I guess the answer here is "No, not yet, sorry."

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement may be you can use **mediaquery** for this. Write like this

```
@media all and (max-width: 848px) {
    .showcase .box{width:33.33%}
    .showcase .box:last-child{display:block;width:212px;float:none}
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/NnZuR/1/

Answer (score 0):

I've come across this issue recently and i think i've come up with a solution that gives the impression that the parent element wraps around it's children elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/partypete25/JCGj6/2/

```
.showcase_wrapper {
    overflow:hidden; /* hides the large bottom border on the bottom row applied on .inner */
    position:relative;
}
.inner {
  display:inline; /* only way to have the div 'hug' it's child elements */
  border-bottom:1000px solid red; /* Any large number will do, or you can make it more precise if you have a set height on your child divs. */

}
.showcase .box {
    background:orange; /*require a background colour otherwise the bottom borders appear from previous rows when items flow onto multiple lines */
    display:inline-block; /*required for it's parents 'inline' display to work effectively. make sure your markup is edited so there is no white space between items */
}
```